# What does the derivative of the sigmoided output of an ANN tell me?

Tags: neural-network

I got really interested in artificial neural networks (ANN) and red into it. But there is one thing i just can't seem to figure out.

When evaluating by how much a weight should be adjusted to reduce the error the ANN makes into account:

- the error (obviously), `*`
- the input (self-explanatory to me as well) `*`
- and the derivative **of** the sigmoid **of** the output (???).

But how does the last point even matter? I know it's supposed to represent how confident the ANN is with this particular weight, but isn't the error the key to how much the weight should be adjusted? Why would I care about how confident my ANN is with this weight if the output is just wrong?

I got my insights (and my confusion) from [this](https://medium.com/technology-invention-and-more/how-to-build-a-simple-neural-network-in-9-lines-of-python-code-cc8f23647ca1#.ts5ltw494) post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitions about how something works are in generally right, but in specifics they might not be right. This is the case for your intuitions of the error function, which are not right. Let's remember how the error is constructed, the output of a single neuron is:

```
o(x, w) = delta(sum w_j x_j + b)
```

Where delta is the activation function. And the error, assuming mean square error, is just the sum of the square differences between neuron output and labels:

```
e(w) = sum (o(x, w) - l)^2
```

To use gradient descent, you take the derivative of the error, which is:

```
e'(w) = sum 2 * (o(x, w) - l) * o'(x, w)
```

This depends on the derivative of o, and by the chain rule this is:

```
o'(x, w) = delta'(sum w_j x_j + b) * x_j
```

Aggregating the derivative of error:

```
e'(w) = sum 2 * (o(x, w) - l) * delta'(sum w_j x_j + b) * x_j
```

So where we have the error (difference), the derivative of the activation evaluated at the neuron output (minus the activation), times the neuron input.
Note that I might have made a mistake or two, but the overall construction is correct. In the end the derivative of the activation (sigmoid) in your case appears because of the application of the chain rule.

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer. It is quite a mathematical apporach though :/ . I really just want to understand why point 3 of my question has to be taken into account. I even used the [formula](https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/800/1*Jow4WVWNOp6rtiJ7vNQ0gQ.png) presented in the post WITHOUT the  derivative part and the result was MORE ACCURATE. I really have trouble understanding the purpose of it.

Comment: @JonasBergner Well it has to be taken into account because if its not, then its wrong. Without it you just have a random formula that seems to work, but no theoretical foundation about why it works. And of course you haven't proven that it works in all cases. There is probably no specific purpose, its part of the formula. The output depends on the activations so it is sensible that the error derivative depends on the activation derivative.

Comment: Ah ok i see. It is like that because the chain rule has to be applied since i have (so to speak) a function in a function. That is why part 3 just has to be there. Thanks, now it makes sense

Comment: @JonasBergner Yes exactly, function composition.

Comment: do you mind explaining to me why taking the derivative helps us. Considering [this image](https://i2.wp.com/kawahara.ca/wp-content/uploads/derivative_of_sigmoid.jpg) . what does the derivative tell us? i know it's used to get the gradient, but that's all i know.

Comment: @JonasBergner The gradient is a generalization of the derivative for functions that take multiple inputs, and have only one output. The gradient always points in the direction of maximum growth in the function, so to descend you take the opposite direction.